# How to find the node where the pig job is running

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I ran a pig work-flow using oozie. The job completed successfully but now I want to know on which slave or master the job ran. My input file is a 1.4GB file which is distributed on the nodes (1 master and 2 slaves).

And I also want to figure out how much time did the pig executed on each node.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Point your web browser to "JobTracker_Machine:50030" and it will presetn you the MapReduce webUI. Here you'll find all the jobs you have run(`Running, Completed and Retired`). Click on the job which you want to analyze and it will give you all the information you need including the node where a particular task has run and the time taken to finish the task.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Oozie Web console and click on the workflow (which contains the pig node).Clicking on the worklfow job will lead to a dialog box (for your workflow) containing details of all the action nodes in the workflow. Select the pig node (which you want to analyse) and a detailed dialog box will appear containing the Job Tracker's URL of that pig job.
There you will find all the details you are looking for.